# ZPL Code 128 multiple subset barcode isn't printing as expected

Tags: barcode, zpl, barcode-printing, zpl-ii, code128

I'm using the following command to print a multi-subset (FS1-128) Code 128 barcode in ZPL:

```
^XA
^FO600,250
^BY3
^BCR,175,N,N,N,N
^FD>;>8019931265099999891>7T77>5000126101000600209^FS
^XZ
```

I'm trying to generate:

Start C + FNC1 + 019931265099999891 + Code A + T77 + Code C + 000126101000600209

When I print it out, the barcode reads:

Start C + FNC1 + 019931265099999891 + Code A + 77 + Code C + 000126101000600209 + 95 + STOP

I know that ZPL added the 95 (symbol check) and STOP to complete the barcode. The Code A section is all wrong though. The T is missing, and the 7s are coded as a pair (i.e. Code C), not single digits. It's like it's printed the Code A, but neglected to switch to that subset...

More info: I'm printing to a Zebra GX420d and a Zebra LP 2844-Z.

Comment: There is online tool to test ZPL code. please try this [ZPL](http://labelary.com/viewer.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hacky fix, but it works.

To get the subset A portion ("T77") of my mostly subset C barcode to print correctly, I translated the individual subset A characters to their subset C equivalents and used those values instead.

To generate:

```
Start C + FNC1 + 019931265099999891 + Code A + T77 + Code C + 000126101000600209
```

My input string ended up being:

```
Start C + FNC1 + 019931265099999891 + Code A + 522323 + Code C + 000126101000600209
```

Which in ZPL is:

```
^FD>;>8019931265099999891>7522323>5000126101000600209^FS
```